# How to validate a binary field using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, rails-activerecord

I want to ensure that a binary field has always value. I added a validation code like below.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :b, presence: true
end
```

However, the change seems to cause the error.

```
$ rails c
> Foo.create(b:File.read('b.jpg'))

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

The error doesn't always appear. Only when the binary data has non-ascii codes.

How can I validate the binary field?

I made the environment like below. A image file(b.jpg, less than 16KB) is also needed.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.0
$ rails new test_binary --database=mysql
$ cd test_binary/
$ rails g model foo b:binary
$ rake db:create db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`File.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-read) returns a `String` that will claim to have UTF-8 encoding by default. That means that this:

```
Foo.create(b: File.read('b.jpg'))
```

is really:

```
some_utf8_string = File.read('b.jpg')
Foo.create(b: some_utf8_string)
```

But a JPEG will rarely be a valid UTF-8 string so you're going to get that `ArgumentError` whenever someone tries to treat it as UTF-8.

You can specify an encoding when you read your JPEG:

```
Foo.create(b: File.read('b.jpeg', encoding: 'binary'))
```

That should get past your encoding problem.